# Animating a UIImage or UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview

I'm trying to animate an image's height (from height of 0 pixels to 480 pixels) to create the effect of the image being rendered top-down.

With an UIImageView i noticed that it appears correct in the Interface Builder. But when it runs in the simulator the size (width and height) is always set to whatever the size of the image is; meaning, if I set the height of the image view to be 50% the original height, the image is still rendered in full height.

I also tried do this effect with an UIImage. However, although the size of the image appears correct, the image is scaled to reflect the size/aspect-ratio.

Question:
How can i achieve this dynamic sizing (i.e. animation of an image's size) while NOT scaling the image? I thought about using CGImageCreateWithMask, but im pretty sure that would create huge performance hiccups.

*** Update ***

The effect that im looking for is this:
Animate an image by making it grow in height, from to-down (like a set of blinds being pulled on a window). This image cannot be scaled (as it would lose the visual effect of looking like a "blind"). This image must also be rendered on top of another image. So there are 2 images total.

*** ANSWER ***

For the top-most imageview, i set the content mode to Top (so it doesnt scale). Then in code, i set the clipsToBounds to True. Now i am able to animate the top-most imageview height thus giving me the effect i am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the original post, here is the answer i seem to have stumbled upon:

For the top-most imageview, i set the content mode to Top (so it doesnt scale). Then in code, i set the clipsToBounds to True. Now i am able to animate the top-most imageview height thus giving me the effect i am looking for.

Answer (score 8):

Use an animation block like so:

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 0)];
imageView.image = ...;
[imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeTop];

[self.view addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];

[UIView animateWithDuration:4.0f
                      delay:1.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^(void) {
                     imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
                 }
                 completion:NULL];
```

Comment: Just curious, are animation blocks better than using the general UIView animations (where you being and commit an animation)?

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar They are now the recommended way to perform animations as of iOS 4.

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar Does my example work? I have tested it locally and it works beautifully.

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar Try it now - should work exactly as you like.

Comment: @Jacob Relkin. This is pretty nifty, but there is one thing missing. Instead of the white overlay, i need the overlay to be another image. Here is a better example/explanation: the overlay image is an x-ray iamge of the background image. So the effect im looking for is the x-ray image being scrolled down from the top (with not scaling...etc) while the background "solid" image ultimately disappears behind the "xray" image.

Comment: @Jacob Relkin. So basically, i cant animate a white overlay. Instead i have 2 images, where one of those images must be resized along the height while NOT scaling the image in any way. Again, for some reason when the ImaeView is rendered in the simulator the image is drawn in its full size, regardless of the size i specify via IB.

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar Is the other image contained within a `UIImageView`?

Comment: @Jacob Relkin. For the time being, yes.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out Animation Blocks. They're documented quite thoroughly here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html

All the code there is relevant, because UIImageView is a subclass of UIView.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Just a suggestion, assume you have two images: A and X (the X-ray image):

```
+-------+               +-------+
|       |               |       |
|       |               |       |
|   A   |               |   X   |
|       |               |       |
|       |               |       |
+-------+               +-------+
```

Dynamically you can create a one-pixel high image (temp), copy the content from X partially, put it on top of A:

```
+-------+   +-------+   +-------+
|       |   | temp1 | < |       |
|       |   +-------+   |       |
|   A   |               |   X   |
|       |               |       |
|       |               |       |
+-------+               +-------+
```

In a loop, dynamically create/resize the temp image, and copy more content from X:

```
+-------+   +-------+   +-------+
|       |   | temp2 | < |       |
|       |   |       |   |       |
|   A   |   +-------+   |   X   |
|       |               |       |
|       |               |       |
+-------+               +-------+

+-------+   +-------+   +-------+
|       |   | temp3 | < |       |
|       |   |       |   |       |
|   A   |   |       |   |   X   |
|       |   +-------+   |       |
|       |               |       |
+-------+               +-------+
+-------+   +-------+   +-------+
|       |   | temp4 | < |       |
|       |   |       |   |       |
|   A   |   |       |   |   X   |
|       |   |       |   |       |
|       |   +-------+   |       |
+-------+               +-------+

+-------+   +-------+   +-------+
|       |   | tempX | < |       |
|       |   |       |   |       |
|   A   |   |       |   |   X   |
|       |   |       |   |       |
|       |   |       |   |       |
+-------+   +-------+   +-------+
```

Comment: I thought of this, but didnt do it because i knew it would be really inefficient, and not to mention probably very slow/choppy.

Answer (score 0):

Try set your UIImageView's **contentMode** property to one of the following value. I think what you need is **UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit**:

```
typedef enum {
    UIViewContentModeScaleToFill,
    UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit,      // contents scaled to fit with fixed aspect. remainder is transparent
    UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill,     // contents scaled to fill with fixed aspect. some portion of content may be clipped.
    UIViewContentModeRedraw,              // redraw on bounds change (calls -setNeedsDisplay)
    UIViewContentModeCenter,              // contents remain same size. positioned adjusted.
    UIViewContentModeTop,
    UIViewContentModeBottom,
    UIViewContentModeLeft,
    UIViewContentModeRight,
    UIViewContentModeTopLeft,
    UIViewContentModeTopRight,
    UIViewContentModeBottomLeft,
    UIViewContentModeBottomRight,
} UIViewContentMode;
```

Comment: I can achieve the effect that im looking for if I use UIViewContentModeTop. Again, this effect looks correct in the IB. But when i run in the simulator the image is ALWAYS displayed as the image's actual size (rather than a size that i specified in the IB).

Comment: I'm confused about your description. 1) Can you post some screen shots? 2) Though you have a set of settings in IB, you code may have modified/overridden them during run time. 3) Simulator may not be accurate, try testing on a real iPhone.

Comment: Imagine a web page being rendered on a very slow connection. You basically see the page being drawn from top-down. Essentially I want to create this effect, where the image is a 320x480 image (UIImage or UIImageView) by slowly increasing the height of the image from y=0 to y=480. The Content Mode is defined as Top (so that the image doesnt scale while the image boundary is being resized).

Comment: Now I see. Have you considered: 1) Fix the position of the image view and its image. 2) Use a animating mask (perhaps another image view) with the same color of your background, to make such an effect?

Comment: When you say "animating mask" do you mean creating a new image on-the-fly and then drawing the blended-result image? If so, wouldnt this be extremely expensive (and choppy) because at each update/cycle a new image is created?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look on [Flip Clock](http://www.voyce.com/index.php/2010/04/10/creating-an-ipad-flip-clock-with-core-animation/) for iPad tutorial. It is with core animation, hence has a performance bonus.

Comment: UH OH.
LOOKS LIKE YOU’VE REACHED A PAGE THAT DOESN’T EXIST.