# iPhone crop part of image, without resizing using animation

Tags: objective-c, animation

OK in my application I have an image which I would like to slowly reveal to the user. So I don't want to resize the image, I want to have the complete image there in the background, then slowly reveal more of the image going from the top down. I am creating a vertical progress bar using animation which I have done using animation, and works fine.

The progress bar itself has an alpha of 0.5 so you can see the image behind it. I use animation and stretch the progress bar when it is animating which is just a view with a set color depending on the progress bar. I don't mind stretching that as that looks fine. However I don't want the image behind the bar to stretch, I want that to only reveal as much of the image as the progress bar has animated. So say the progress bar is 80% complete, then then I should see 80% of the height of the image behind it, the width will never change, and the image behind it is not resized, just more of it is revealed.

I tried using the same code I use with the progress bars on the image, but it looks inconsistent as the progress bars will be at different levels and the stretched image looks odd.

I have been looking at different ways of cropping code dynamically, but I can't seem to find any which do it in an animation. Are there any built in methods for carrying out such a task? A lot of the crop code I have found, seem to resize the image.

I am been animating my progress bars using this to animate

```
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:3.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,transformValue);
    image.transform = transform;
    image.center = CGPointMake(xValue, yValue);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I was hoping you could use something similar for an animating a crop of an image.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

After a hell of a lot of testing, I have managed to get to this point:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{


                         UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_connectMe.png"];
                     CGImageRef tmpImgRef = image.CGImage;
                     CGImageRef topImgRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(tmpImgRef, CGRectMake(0, 30, image.size.width, image.size.height));

                     UIImage *topImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:topImgRef];
                    imgView.image = topImage;
                     imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 180, topImage.size.width, topImage.size.height);

                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     NSLog(@"Final method");


                 }
 ];
```

This will crop image in half, and keep the original image size, however the problem is, that  the new cropped image is applied instantly in this line of code

```
 UIImage *topImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:topImgRef];
                        imgView.image = topImage;
```

It isn't animated, whereas this part

imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 180, topImage.size.width, topImage.size.height);

is animated. I would need to somehow animate the change in frame of the CGI image so the image is slowly cropped to whatever size it needs to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FINALLY!!

After two days of playing around with this, finally found the answer. Was doing some more testing and searching around when I found this thread

[Animating a UIImage or UIImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772736/animating-a-uiimage-or-uiimageview)

I altered the code to suit my needs and ended up with this

```
-(void)cropAnimateBottom
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bar.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 150, image.size.width, 0)];
    imageView.image = image;
    [imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeBottom];

    [self.view addSubview:imageView];


    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^(void) {
                         imageView.frame = CGRectMake(150, 150, image.size.width, -image.size.height);
                     }
                     completion:NULL];

}
```

I set contentMode bottom and as you can see set the image height in the animation block to be MINUS the images height. If you want to animate from the top down, then just do it the other way around and change the content mode to be top instead, i.e.

```
-(void)cropAnimateTop
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bar.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, image.size.width, 0)];
    imageView.image = image;
    [imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeTop];

    [self.view addSubview:imageView];


    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^(void) {
                         imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, image.size.width, image.size.height);
                     }
                     completion:NULL];

}
```

Hope that helps other people who are trying to achieve the same thing!!